# Implementation details of scheme library procedures?

Tags: scheme, definition

As per my understanding scheme procedures like map,apply,append etc are written in scheme itself. Is there an easy way to see the implementation of these procedues right inside the REPL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe there is a standard way to dump the source code of a procedure, but a lot of the list functions are defined [here](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1-reference.scm), and you can look through the source code for your implementation to see the rest.  Note that `apply` is probably a primitive, though.

Comment: @sudhirc: You probably can't, since it relies on the details of procedure application in ways that you normally can't use in Scheme.

Comment: JFGI: http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=implement+scheme+apply

Comment: @Marcin: Those are for implementing your own Scheme interpreter, I think.  Is there a way to define `apply` for an existing Scheme system without using any primitives that are equivalent to `apply`?

Comment: This is a standard exercise. The answer is yes, you can google it. This smells terribly like you are trying to get us to do your homework.

Comment: @Marcin: Your criticism is valid but my original question is about viewing the pre implemented procedure details in REPL. Asking for apply implementation was an impulsive comment after searching through the SRFI-1 library for an implementation. I will be more careful in future.